# New to Message broker 7

Tags: message, messagebroker

I am new to message broker and I am having a problem.

What I need to do is this.
Check the message que.
If the message que is backed up I need to release one message at a time every 7 seconds.  Not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by release here? Do you just want to consume that message or put it to a failure queue of some kind?

Assuming that is the case you could use a combination of the Timeout Control node to drive a flow every 7 seconds and an MQGET Node to consume the message (and optionally wire an MQOutput node to put the message to a different queue).

The tricky part is going to be determining if the queue is backed up, I would use a Java Compute Node and make calls using the MQ Java Base API using PCF to check the queue depth.

The flow would then only propagate as far as the MQGET node if the queue depth was above a certain threshold.

You can get more information about using the PCF classes from the API docs:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.java.doc%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fmq%2Fpcf%2FPCFMessageAgent.html

Comment: I think the requirement is, if we send one message, next message should not be sent before 7 seconds. I don't think PCF is required here. Just Timeout Control and MQInput are enough.